# How to ask a question about Etruscan?

Tags: discussion

I had read that questions about Etruscan language are considered on-topic here ([Why don't we rename this SE to Classics or Classical Languages?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/417/why-dont-we-rename-this-se-to-classics-or-classical-languages)), so I asked a question about the Etruscan language: [How would you say "The Etruscan language died two thousand years ago and nobody understands it." in Etruscan?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15564/how-would-you-say-the-etruscan-language-died-two-thousand-years-ago-and-nobody)

Basically, I asked for a help with translating a sentence to Etruscan, I provided my own translation, and I, basically, explained each morpheme, as well as sometimes (for the words I have estimated are not so well-known) where I got that morpheme from.

While I received some upvotes, I received no answers or even a comment. So, what do you think, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's likely is that no one here can answer your question. You might try reaching out to an actual Etruscologist, a linguist who studies Etruscan or a Classicist who works on Etruria.

Comment: I agree. The questions are good but nobody in this community can answer. The only solution is to attract new users who know Etruscan, but don't ask me how.