# Do high-reputation members here actually speak Latin?

Tags: discussion

I am interested, do high-reputation members here actually speak Latin? Would they be capable of holding some conversation in Latin?

I don't think I would be capable of holding some advanced conversation in Latin, but I am able to make YouTube videos in Latin by reading from a script I wrote using a dictionary and sometimes grammar tables. My latest YouTube video in Latin is [my video explaining why I don't believe in afterlife](https://youtube.com/watch?v=gx1hhczsdAE&feature=share).

Comment: Note that a high reputation on this website says relatively little about Latin skills – obviously one won't go very far if one knows no Latin at all, but, for example, some clearly very knowledgeable people simply do not write that many answers.

Comment: Relevant: https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-would-you-feel-about-more-specialized-chat-rooms

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel And to add on to that, reputation can be gained from both answers *and* questions, so it's really not a good gauge of one's Latinity at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that most of our high-reputation users have the potential to acquire conversational skills in Latin quickly but don't have such a skill active now.
Some do have that skill, but I'm not sure how many.

The reason is two-fold: many have learned Latin for a purpose other than conversing in it and those who wish to speak may struggle to find opportunities.
But once one is fluent in written Latin, learning to hold a simple conversation in it is a minor task.

That said, some of the active users here do have a conversational Latin skill already.
That skill will probably not correlate very strongly with reputation on the site.
It can also be difficult to tell who are able to use Latin that way, as it's a skill not often advertised.

Our site has its own [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm), and we do occasionally chat there in Latin.
The vast majority of everything is in English, though.

Answer (score 5):

Reading, writing, speaking, and hearing are four very different skills in any language.

For instance, I recently read Camus' novel *L'étranger* in French (all English translations have a terrible first sentence and go down hill from there).

But I can write only poor French. I can barely understand spoken French, and no one would want to hear me attempt speaking it. I have only one of the four skills, and I don't expect that situation to change.

It's very likely that many people on this site are in a similar situation with respect to Latin, and they are quite capable of answering very difficult questions about it, so long as their answers are in English.